# Mongoose - aggregate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a function to abstract the Model used to query my MongoDB.

I have multiple models using the same schema, but I need to use only 1 function.

I am doing this:

```
const pricesSchema = {
    sold:...,
    createdAt:...
}


const Model1 = mongoose.model('Model1', pricesSchema);
const Model2 = mongoose.model('Model2', pricesSchema);

const getModelFromString = (model) => {
    switch(model) {
        case 'cars' || 'boats': {
            return Model1
        }
        case 'houses' || 'buildings': {
            return Model2
        }
    }
}
```

But when I consume these models in an abstract way, I am facing the following issue:

```
// ...
const Model = getModelFromString('cars')
Model.aggregate(...)


// TypeError: Model.aggregate is not a function ....
```

Comment: i guess the `dex` is a typo for model

Comment: yes! it was an issue just from copy pasting, ammended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not a proper check in `switch` case. If you want to check for multiple values in a single `case`, you can try the following:

```
case 'cars':
case 'boats':
    // your logic
```

Or another approach:

```
switch (true) {
    case (['cars', 'boats'].includes(model)):
        // your logic 
}
```

Comment: Very simple yet silly mistake of mine. Cheers!